# why "\" is truncated from string "videos\1_visualisation.mp4"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

Below is my sample angular js code . Factory consist of list of video sources.

```
    var videoPlayer=angular.module('videoPlayer',[])

videoPlayer.controller("videoplayer",["$scope","videolist",function($scope,videolist)
{
    $scope.position=0;
    $scope.audiolength=videolist.sources.length;
    $scope.videosrc=videolist.sources[$scope.position];
    console.log($scope.videosrc)
}])

videoPlayer.factory('videolist',function()
{
    var videolist={};
    videolist.sources=[
    'videos\1_visualisation.mp4',
    'videos\2_visualisation.mp4',
    'videos\3_visualisation.mp4'
    ]
    return videolist;
})
```

why does "\" is turncated from the string.

$scope.videosrc=videolist.sources[$scope.position];

returns  "videos1_visualisation.mp4" . why does this happen

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\`:

```
videolist.sources=[
    'videos\\1_visualisation.mp4',
    'videos\\2_visualisation.mp4',
    'videos\\3_visualisation.mp4'
    ]
```

Comment: what if incase of string is like videos\pet-1_visualisation.mp4

Comment: is there anyother way without using \\

Comment: @bharath I don't think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character starts an [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings) (in this case `\1` is `1` because it isn't defined to be anything special, `\n` OTOH would be a new line).

If you want to include one as data in a string literal, you have to use the escape sequence for it: `\\`

Comment: what if incase of string is like videos\pet-1_visualisation.mp4

Comment: @bharath — Then you do exactly what I said to do in this answer. Use a double \

Comment: is there anyother way without using \\

Comment: @bharath — You could use a unicode escape sequence, but that would just make it hard to read and you'd have to look up the code point of a \ to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are interpreted as beginning "escape sequences" used to denote special characters.  For example, `\n` indicates a newline.  If a given number or letter isn't part of a recognized escape sequence, the character itself is just displayed.  In your case, `\1` is being rendered as `1`.  To preserve a slash, either escape the slash itself...

```
'videos\\1_visualisation.mp4'
```

...or, if you just need to preserve the path...

```
'videos/1_visualisation.mp4'
```

Comment: is there anyother way without using \\

Comment: You could probably use a forward slash instead.  That should still be a valid path.